# I'm facing issue in understanding the ReactJS code, on the state change. Can anyone explain me this weird o/p?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Sometimes value of *title* changes to **Updated1** and sometimes to **Updated2**. Please help me understand whats going on here.

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import "./ExpenseItem.css";
import ExpenseDate from "./ExpenseDate";

function ExpenseItem(props) {
   
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
    let i = 0;
   
    const handleClick = () => {
        i++;
        setTitle('Updated' + i);
    };

    return (
        <div className="expense-item">
            <div className="expense-item__description">
                <h2>
                    {title}
                </h2>
            </div>
            <button onClick = {handleClick}>Change Title</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How it works is that when you press your button, you call the `handleClick` method which increases `i` by one and shows `Updated1`. The next time you press the button, it becomes `Updated2`.

However, because you define `let i = 0`, there is a chance it can become `Updated1` again when the component re-renders and produce unpredictable results.

If you want to let `i` increment each time you press your button, I suggest creating a new state to store `i` via `setState`. This is actually a simple example provided by React.

I don't recommend storing it in a global scope like the earlier answer by @Leslie Alldridge

```js
import {useState} from 'react';
import "./ExpenseItem.css";
import ExpenseDate from "./ExpenseDate";

function ExpenseItem(props) {
   
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
   
    const handleClick = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
        setTitle('Updated' + count);
    };

    return (
        <div className="expense-item">
            <div className="expense-item__description">
                <h2>
                    {title}
                </h2>
            </div>
            <button onClick = {handleClick}>Change Title</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: @Root, it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `let i = 0;` from within the component as it will re-render and set `i` back to `0` again.

```
let i = 0;
function App(props) {
   
  const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title);
  
 
  const handleClick = () => {
      i++;
      setTitle('Updated' + i);
  };

  return (
      <div className="expense-item">
          <div className="expense-item__description">
              <h2>
                  {title}
              </h2>
          </div>
          <button onClick = {handleClick}>Change Title</button>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```